# vue.js: Watched input not fired on every keypress

Tags: vue.js

I have an `input` whose model property is beeing watched. The problem is that the watch method is not called on every key press in **Chrome Android** devices. If I tap the input text, then it gets called. 
It did worked in the past and I don't know what happened.
On **Chrome Desktop it works** (that is: the `watch` for `text` is beeing called on every keypress).

Input:

```
  <input id="input-message" ref="input-message" :disabled="disabled"
  @focus="$emit('focus')" @keyup.enter="sendMessage" 
  v-model="text" type="text" placeholder="Start typing..." 
  class="form-control">
```

Watch:

```
  watch: {
    disabled: function(val) {
      if (!val) {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.$refs["input-message"].focus();
        });
      }
    },
    text: function(val) {
      var mode = this.micMode;
      if (this.userAgent !== "ios") {
        let isEmpty = val.length === 0;

        if (mode === 1 && !isEmpty) {
          this.micMode = 0;
        } else if (mode === 0 && isEmpty) {
          this.micMode = 1;
        }
      }

    }
  },
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For languages that require an [IME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) (Chinese, Japanese, Korean etc.),
> you’ll notice that v-model doesn’t get updated during IME composition.
> If you want to cater for these updates as well, use input event
> instead.
>
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#vmodel-ime-tip

you can change `v-model="model"` to `:value="text" @input="text = $event.target.value"` and the watcher should be triggered as expected