# Vue watch unexpected response with Android Chrome

Tags: android, vue.js

I have a tagger component that filters an array of tags. Simplified version here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/p955o6149m

It revolves around this input:

```
<input
  v-if="showInput"
  type="text"
  class="tag_input__input"
  :id="'tag_input__input' + fieldName(0,'input')"
  v-model="tag"
  @keydown.delete="deleteLast"
  @keydown.tab="autocomplete($event)"
  @blur="queueAutoComplete($event)">
```

And a watcher...

```
watch: {
  tag() {
    console.log("watched tag change!");
    var self = this;
    if (self.t) {
      clearTimeout(self.t);
      self.t = false;
    }
    if (self.tag.indexOf(",") >= 0) {
      var bits = self.tag.split(",");
      if (bits[0] != "") {
        this.addStringTag(bits[0].trim());
      }
    }
    self.t = setTimeout(function() {
      self.showTags();
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

On a desktop, it works great:

https://youtu.be/YlyiWoVl9Ks

But on an Android Mobile Chrome, the tagging seems to be almost completely out of sync:

https://youtu.be/0pZ0cXfpX4U

The model only seems to update on / after certain keypresses (like space or backspace).

I console log a few things, and it seems like v-model isn't updating. This is weird though, as I have a stripped back version [here that works fine](https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/2455415c200d13964316004405fec75b?editors=0100).

How do I stop the latency happening on a mobile?

Answer (score 4):

you can change

```
v-model="model"
```

to

```
:value="text" 
@input="text = $event.target.value"
```

and the watcher will be triggered as expected.

Because

> For languages that require an [IME][1] (Chinese, Japanese, Korean etc.),
> you’ll notice that v-model doesn’t get updated during IME composition.
> If you want to cater for these updates as well, use input event
> instead.
>
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#vmodel-ime-tip

Answer (score 2):

see this answer for solution/workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49944252/960380

In a nutshell, if you are using an "input method" (Gboard on my phone with swipe does this), the input event won't be raised until you actually pick a word (by clicking, or pressing space etc).

There is a brief mention here in Vue docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#vmodel-ime-tip